# Using oauth for google apps for domain standard?

Tags: oauth, google-apps

I'm trying to use oauth for the gdata python api with our google apps for domain standard edition users.  I can't figure out how to get the secret key because it is not listed in the management console.  Is this not possible for google apps standard?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No. Two legged OAuth keys are only available for Premier and Education editions of Google Apps.
http://www.google.com/support/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=61017