# Generating valid oauth token and secret for gmail imap?

Tags: oauth, gmail, google-apps

I have been searching everywhere for a Java port of [xoauth.py](http://code.google.com/p/google-mail-xoauth-tools/wiki/XoauthDotPyRunThrough). As I really want to use the same authentication process in my java web app.

I have tried using the GoogleOAuthHelper to generate the token and secret but when I plugin them in to the [google mail java sample](http://code.google.com/p/google-mail-xoauth-tools/wiki/JavaSampleCode), I get errors back saying invalid credentials.

If anyone can help I would be very appreciative. I have been stuck on this for sooo long now.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using oauth for google apps for domain standard?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2246630/using-oauth-for-google-apps-for-domain-standard)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the links on this page https://developers.google.com/google-apps/gmail/oauth_libraries

and 
https://developers.google.com/google-apps/gmail/#oauth_access_to_imap_and_smtp

This is assuming that the service you want to access is gmail (since you tagged your question gmail). If you're looking to use a different service, (say Drive) then your starting point is the api console at https://code.google.com/apis/console