# oauth.py java equivalent

Tags: java, python, oauth, gmail, jakarta-mail

Looking for a java equivalent file for [xoauth.py](http://code.google.com/p/google-mail-xoauth-tools/wiki/XoauthDotPyRunThrough). I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12243874/234110), but did not help much. Any pointers/help/guidance/reference ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this awesome API library called [Scribe](https://github.com/fernandezpablo85/scribe-java). Now my life is too simple with only Pure-Java! A special thanks to [Pablo](https://github.com/fernandezpablo85) for his creation(s)