# Generate Gmail authentification token

Tags: node.js, google-oauth, gmail-api, google-api-nodejs-client

I am trying to generate a Gmail authentication token to use in my NodeJS server for sending email notifications.
Right now I have something like this (I'm not the one who did that) but I need to change the email address and I'm having issues with this:

```
exports.mail = 
{
    service: 'Gmail',
    auth: {
        user: 'gmail_address_here',
        pass: '16_characters_token_here'
    }
}
```

I created a few projects in Google Console and tried messing around and I also followed the guide provided by Google but no luck. I also checked this: [Generating valid oauth token and secret for gmail imap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12243629/generating-valid-oauth-token-and-secret-for-gmail-imap) as well as https://scotch.io/tutorials/easy-node-authentication-google and other guides and I always end up with a client ID and a client secret as well as the JSON file with the info inside but it doesn't work in my app.

Any ideas?

Comment: This is coming straight from Google Documentation for [Node.js](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/nodejs). Try working with the Quickstart example and work from there. Hope this helps and good luck!

Comment: Thanks @Andres. I already did that but it didn't work out. I found another guide however and I ended up altering the code a bit.